# SQL server INSERT Using WITH

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables
student and course_log

I have Students already in students table, I need to insert into course_log for each student a standard course (UNI 101) that all have to take or have take.

So if there are 10 students there will be 10 entries in the course_log table for each student with course UNI 101

I was thinking of using a with clause but it does not work that way i think

```
USE [university]
GO
with studentid as ( select id as stdID from student)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[course_log]
           ([course_name]
           ,[course_code]
           ,[STUDENT_ID])
     VALUES
           ('STANDARD COURSE FOR ALL STUDENTS'
           ,'UNI 101'
           ,studentid.stdID)
```

The other one that was coming to my mind was to use a while loop ( as MSSQL does not have for loop) but i was actually thinking if the above would be much easier and doable.

Comment: `insert into ... select`

Comment: You mean the content of this "select id as stdID from student" you need to insert into other table?

Comment: How about this " VALUES
           ('STANDARD COURSE FOR ALL STUDENTS'
           ,'UNI 101'" its all rows affected would have this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of WITH clause

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[course_log]
           ([course_name]
           ,[course_code]
           ,[STUDENT_ID])
SELECT
      'STANDARD COURSE FOR ALL STUDENTS'
       ,'UNI 101'
       ,stdID 
FROM student
```

Comment: Ok,this was very simple. I feel soo... stupid.It worked. Thanks!